# Swift, Combine, cancel on the flight and replace with the new request operator

Tags: ios, swift, combine

I've got this network call for fetching images.

```swift
func load() {
        guard let url = URL(string: urlString)
        else { return }

        subscription = URLSession.shared.dataTaskPublisher(for: url)
            .map({ UIImage(data: $0.data) })
            .replaceError(with: nil)
            .receive(on: RunLoop.main)
            .sink(receiveValue: { [weak self] in self?.image = $0 })
    }
```

This is triggered by the text field being filled. After each letter is typed, I would like my publisher to wait with the execution for let's say 2 seconds, unless a user typed another letter. If that happens, I'd like the timer to reset to 2 seconds again.

Is there any on the fly **cancel** operator if the new request has been sent in the meanwhile?

Thanks for all the help.

Comment: It isn't the publisher that you need to delay. It is the call to `load`. How is `load` called?  If you invoke it in a combine pipeline then you can use the `debounce` operator.

Comment: But will debounce cancel any previous call of load if such happens?

Comment: Don't even fire the network call until the debounce expires. Once you have started the network request you may as well let it complete.

Comment: Are you using UIKit or SwiftUI?

Comment: Since you aren't using the data from the text field in the URL, why do you want to do this?

Comment: What is the minimum OS version this needs to work for?

Comment: Isn't this exactly the example from the very first Combine video? https://developer.apple.com/wwdc19/721

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a pretty standard thing to do with a reactive library and easily accomplished. The `switchToLatest` operator is the one that does the magic.

```
@available(iOS 14.0, *)
final class ViewController: UIViewController {
    var textField: UITextField!
    var image: UIImage?
    var cancelBag = Set<AnyCancellable>()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        textField.textPublisher // this is from the `CombineCocoa` library
            .debounce(for: 2, scheduler: RunLoop.main)
            .compactMap { makeURL(from: $0) }
            .map {
                URLSession.shared.dataTaskPublisher(for: $0)
                    .catch { _ in Empty() } // what do you want to do with loading errors?
            }
            .switchToLatest()
            .map { UIImage(data: $0.data) }
            .receive(on: RunLoop.main)
            .sink(receiveValue: { [weak self] in self?.image = $0 })
            .store(in: &cancelBag)
    }
}

func makeURL(from: String?) -> URL? {
    // build and return the correct URL for the image request
    fatalError()
}
```

Comment: A simple `flatMap` would not cancel any previous request that might have been in flight. Using `flatMap` might ultimately show the wrong image. You are right about the `compactMap` though. I will update.